# How to read RTS/CTS pins' values on Linux?

Tags: linux, serial-port, embedded-linux

I would like to know the status of RTS/CTS pins on the serial port on my Linux machine.

Also, since I am using /dev/ttyUSB0 will the same mechanism work?

Regards,
Aakash

Comment: Try here http://linux.about.com/od/mdm_howto/a/hwtmdm08t02.htm

Answer (score 3):

It is usually recommended to use [termios](http://linux.die.net/man/3/termios) for interacting with a serial port but I believe RTS/CTS access is not supported. You will need to use ioctl(2) along with TIOCMGET and TIOCMSET. You can see an example [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6908).

Your USB dongle probably supports RTS/CTS but there are many different USB serial devices and not all of them do. Also, latency may be an issue. [FTDI](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/FAQs.htm) (probably the most popular USB serial chip provider) takes up to 3 characters to stop transmitting after CTS stops being active.

Comment: The `ioctl()`s are the conventional method, but are not POSIX compliant.  See Chapter 4 of this [POSIX guide](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html#5_1_2).

Answer (score 1):

I used gtkterm and it shows the status of the pins in the bottom status bar. This worked properly with /dev/ttyUSB0 also.

Answer (score 1):

statserial will display serial port modem status lines instantly, check manual page [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/statserial)

```
statserial /dev/<device_name>
```