# Hardware Control Flow RTS/CTS does not work in Linux (e.g. Data still able to flow over Tx even if CTS is disabled)

Tags: c++, linux, serial-port, control-flow

I am using SUSE Linux and trying to communicate using serial device with RTS/CTS control flow. My code is as follows:

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE
#define _SVID_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>      // standard input / output functions
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>     // string function definitions
#include <unistd.h>     // UNIX standard function definitions
#include <fcntl.h>      // File control definitions
#include <errno.h>      // Error number definitions
#include <termios.h>    // POSIX terminal control definitions

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    // open port
    int USB = open( "/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR| O_NOCTTY );

    // set parameters
    struct termios tty;
    struct termios tty_old;
    memset (&tty, 0, sizeof tty);

    /* Error Handling */
    if ( tcgetattr ( USB, &tty ) != 0 )
    {
    cout << "Error " << errno << " from tcgetattr: " << strerror(errno) << endl;
    }

    /* Save old tty parameters */
    tty_old = tty;

    /* Set Baud Rate */
    cfsetospeed (&tty, (speed_t)B9600);
    cfsetispeed (&tty, (speed_t)B9600);

    /* Setting other Port Stuff */
    tty.c_cflag     &=  ~PARENB;        // Make 8n1
    tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSTOPB;
    tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSIZE;
    tty.c_cflag     |=  CS8;
    tty.c_cflag     |=  CRTSCTS;       // set RTS/CTS flow control

    tty.c_cc[VMIN]      =   1;                  // read doesn't block
    tty.c_cc[VTIME]     =   5;                  // 0.5 seconds read timeout

    /* Make raw */
    cfmakeraw(&tty);

    /* Flush Port, then applies attributes */
    tcflush( USB, TCIFLUSH );
    if ( tcsetattr ( USB, TCSANOW, &tty ) != 0){
        cout << "Error " << errno << " from tcsetattr" << endl;
    }

    // write
    unsigned char cmd[] = "Message\r";
    int n_written = 0;

    do {
        n_written += write( USB, &cmd[n_written], 1 );
    }
    while (cmd[n_written-1] != '\r' && n_written > 0);

    return 0;
}
```

I executed my code and use oscilloscope to measure the CTS+, RTS+ and Tx+ pins of the connected RS422 sockets of the serial to USB box (http://www.easysync-ltd.com/product/645/usb2-h-6008-m.html) which I jumped two terminals to be connected together using cross cable. The result is that the voltage of CTS+ and RTS+ pins remained unchanged after writing the data even if the control flow was already enable in line:

```
tty.c_cflag     |=  CRTSCTS;       // set RTS/CTS flow control
```

Another incorrect situation is that the data still flow through Tx even in the case that CTS is disable.

Could anyone help me with this problem? Or If someone uses to use serial communication with RTS/CTS before, could you suggest the way you done it?

Comment: Unchanged at what value? If you've connected CTS to RTS, and the initial value is the expected one, then I guess the port driver never needs to change it?

Comment: I think I connect CTS to RTS properly but the values of CTS and RTS were unchanged (low). However, there is still a data flow on TX and the receiver can get the data correctly.

Comment: Right ... I might be mistaken, perhaps there *needs* to be edges on RTS/CTS even if no actual waiting is needed. It's been too long since I used RTS/CTS. :(

Comment: Which OS/platform did you use?

Comment: Quoting from [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html), *"The **CTS** signal is received from the other end of the serial cable. A space voltage indicates that is alright to send more serial data from your workstation."* and *"The **RTS** signal is set to the space voltage by your workstation to indicate that more data is ready to be sent."*  So the low voltages you measure should be okay, and the transmission correct.  Nothing seems amiss.

Comment: *"I jumped two terminals to be connected together"* -- The test you should be doing is toggling the **CTS** output of the receiving terminal.  You have not described doing anything with this end of the comm link.

Comment: @sawdust 
1) Sorry, may be I described my problem not clear enough. I already added another problem I found into the post itself that the data is still able to be sent even if the CTS is disabled.

2) I use cross cable which connect CTS from a terminal to the RTS of the another one.

Comment: *"...even if the CTS is disabled."* -- Please describe how you are doing this, and how you have confirmed the signals on the wire.

Comment: I measured the signal using oscilloscope and CTS has high voltage.

Comment: Then check the Linux serial driver's view of this CTS state.  Look in the file `/proc/tty/driver/serial` or similar.  You could debug your serial port.  Is the CTS an actual UART/USART input that internally inhibits the transmitter?  Or is CTS a GPIO that generates an interrupt, and the driver responds by disabling transmission?

Comment: I already check the file you suggested. I seems like when I plug my device, there is no change to `/proc/tty/driver/serial` but there is a change on `/proc/tty/driver/usbserial`. This might be because I connect the serial devices using usb to serial box.

Anyway, I cannot get much information from the file `/proc/tty/driver/usbserial`. When I connect 4 ports, the texts in the file looks like this:
    `0: module:ftdi_sio name:"FTDI USB Serial Device" vendor:0403 product:6011 num_ports:1 port:1 path:usb-0000:02:03.0-2 ... and so on`

Comment: Then write a utility program to get the state of the control lines using the **TIOCMGET** ioctl.  See [this](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html#5_1_1) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385272/how-to-read-rts-cts-pins-values-on-linux

Comment: Thanks, I used that already. Anyway, RTS/CTS still not work. The data is still able flow regardless of the value of RTS/CTS (The values of RTS/CTS cannot be changed automatically from the HW control flow anyway).